# Single choice lemma, is my proof valid?

Tags: real-analysis

This is from Lemma 3.5.11 in Tao’s analysis 1

Single Choice Lemma:

Let $n \geq 1$ be a natural number, and for each natural number $1 \leq i \leq n$, let $X_i$ be a non-empty set. Then, there exists an $n$-tuple $(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ such that $x_i \in X_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Using induction, after showing that it’s true for the base case, the author assumes that the claim is true for some $n$ and wants to show that it also true for the $n+1$ case. He does this by:

Using the induction hypothesis, we can find an n-tuple $(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ such that $x_i \in X_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. Also, since $X_{n+1}$ is non-empty, we can find an object $a$ st $a \in X_{n+1}$. Thus, we can define the n+1-tuple $(y_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n+1}$ by setting $y_i=x_i$ when $1 \le i \le n$ and $y_i=a$ when $i=n+1$. It is clear that $y_i \in X_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n+1$, thus closing the induction.

I understand that the above works but instead of doing the above, is it possible to skip the induction hypothesis in the inductive step from $n$ to $n+1$ by:

Since for all $1 \le i \le n$, $X_i$ is non-empty. Then there exists an $x_i \in X_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. Thus, we can define the n+1-tuple $(y_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n+1}$ by setting $y_i=x_i$ when $1 \le i \le n+1$. It is clear that $y_i \in X_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n+1$, thus closing the induction.

I asked on another platform and was told that I couldn’t do the above/wasn’t valid because I am not allowed to make arbitrary $n$ choices like that. I sort of understand this but at the same time, I don’t think I am because I am precisely making only $n+1$ choices. It's still a finite number and not arbitrary I think.

Another person told me I was being circular since the lemma is just equivalent to being able to make multiple choices. I agree with this also but isn't the author also making multiple choices(2 choices) since he is using both the 2-tuple and $a$. Why would he allowed be to make 2 choices here?

Would be helpful to me if anyone could elaborate/veirfy

Comment: What is the difference between your argument and the following: if $X_i$ ius non-empty for all $i\in I$ then there is an $x_i\in X_i$ for all $i\in I$ and therefore a tuple, namely $(x_i:i\in I)$, in the product. Hence, any nonempty (finite or infinite) product of nonempty sets is nonempty.

Comment: [What I mean is that the argument I just wrote definitely has something going on in the background -- the axiom of choice -- while the one you are checking should have no need of such devices. And, crucially, if your argument uses some form of the axiom of choice anyway, where does it come up? Does it matter, or can it be removed?]

Comment: (Separately from all that, why are you framing your argument as an induction?)

Comment: The author has done some inductions in past proposition where induction hypothesis wasn't used I think. my understanding is that having an induction doesn't make it wrong even if the induction hypothesis is not used

Comment: For the difference between what I wrote and what you wrote, I don't see the difference, I'm not too sure what happens in the infinite case to be honest. For the axiom of choice, I havent quite learnt that yet.

Comment: In the finite case, I do think I can just write what you wrote instead of using then induction. I'm guessing this is wrong but I'm not too sure why.

Comment: Your proposed argument actually assumes the statement you're trying to prove! (Don't feel bad, this often happens when we are learning about foundations of math and trying to prove things we have taken for granted beforehand.)

Comment: @Gnolius You are correct that induction doesn’t necessarily need to use the inductive hypothesis, but I’ve literally only ever seen this used once. It’s in the proof of the statement $\forall n (n = 0 \lor \exists m (n = S(m)))$. Induction without using the inductive hypothesis is equivalent to this statement.

Comment: @GregMartin, I think I understand this now, I'm not allowed to make more than 1 choices at a time yet. I'm still confused with the author's proof, since wouldn't he still be making 2 choices, the first from the set of n-tuples and the second from $X_{n+1}$. 2 choices are alot less than an arbitrary n of them but wouldn't even just 2 choices be impossible here.

Comment: If you've done any coding, here's an analogy: you're writing in a language that doesn't have loops. You're allowed to make single statements; then certainly you can make two statements, one after the other. You could (if you felt like taking the time) make 100 statements, one by one. But you have no way of making *an arbitrary number* of statements—that would require a loop. The same thing is going on here: 1 or 2 or 100 choices is fine, but an arbitrary number $n$ of choices isn't.

Comment: It is much clearer now and I think i got it this time, hopefully. Let me try to elaborate on what your saying about 1 or 2 or 100 statements. For the $100$th case(or any specific number I have in mind) itself and nothing else, i can proof that the claim is true by one by one listing out the statements, there exists $x_1 \in X_1, x_2 \in X_2,..,x_{100} \in X_{100}$. This would be a valid proof for the $100$th case. But for an arbitrary number n, its not possible to just do this same listing out since I would have to somehow be making listing out an arbitrary n number of statements